# How do you create instances of an plugin using cloud9's architect.js?

Tags: node.js, plugins, dependency-injection

I am investigating using architect for organising my node projects

https://github.com/c9/architect

On slide 66 of the following presentation it shows how you are supposed to create instances of the plugin.

http://www.slideshare.net/sergimansilla/architecting-large-nodejs-applications-14912706

Here is the snippet:

```
function startNewGame(name) {
   var game = db.createNewGame(name);

   var config = [
      {
        packagePath: "./game-status",
        game: game
      }
   ];

   architect.createApp(/* snip  */)
```

I can't work out what params are supposed to go into createApp. In the docs it only mentions a  config that has been loaded from disk like so

```
var architect_config = architect.loadConfig(path.join(__dirname, 'plugins.json'));
```

When I try and load the config directly like in the above example, it throws an error

```
/code/npm_module_tests/architect_test/node_modules/architect/architect.js:423
            throw err;
                  ^
Error: Plugin is missing the setup function {"packagePath":"./app"}
```

Here is my code

```
var path = require('path');
var architect = require('architect');

var config = [{
  "packagePath": "./app2"
}]


var arch = architect.createApp(config, function (){
  console.log('application started');
});
```

So how do you create instances of an plugin using architect.js?

EDIT:

I've read through the code and it seems like the config needs to be prepared by the loadConfig method which assumes the config is on disk. How then are you able to inject instances of a plugin into the config as the slides suggest?

Comment: typo parckagePath should be packagePath

Comment: Thanks but that was not the problem. That was just me typing the slide out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `architect.resolveConfig`, loadConfig uses it internally for the case when config is in a js file

```
function loadConfig(configPath, callback) {
  var config = require(configPath);
  var base = dirname(configPath);

  return resolveConfig(config, base, callback);
}
```

try

```
var plugins = [{
   provides: ["myService"], consumes: [],
   setup: function(options, imports, register){
      console.log(arguments)
      register(null, { myService: {}})
   }
}, {
   provides: [], consumes: ["myService"],
   setup: function(options, imports, register){
      console.log(imports.myService)
   }
}, {
   packagePath: "./app"
   game: game
}]

architect.resolveConfig(plugins, __dirname, function(err, config) {
    var app = architect.createApp(config, function(err, app) {
        console.log(err, app)
    })
    app.on("service", function (service) {
        console.log(service)
    })
})
```

or the sync version

```
var config = architect.resolveConfig(plugins, __dirname)
var app = architect.createApp(config)
app.on("service", function (service) {
    console.log(service)
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not sure how you are supposed to inject an instance into a plugins imports (eg. imports.myGameInsatnce). What you are showing me is how to export a plugin. I can see how you could use register() to export an an instance but how do you pass that instance to other plugins? It sounded like from the slides that it was a built in feature.

Comment: I've updated the example to show usage of consumes array too, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not really. You did help me with the config options though. What the slide shows is calling startNewGame which creates a game instance and then passes that into another plugin inside its imports object. So the module that is in the consumes array is actually a game instance not a singleton. Is it acceptable to call createApp multiple times? What happens when you have more than one thing to instanciate? How does the plugin system help you in passing around instances as dependancies? Am I supposed to ask the module for the instance like imports.gameManager.getGameInstance(id)

Comment: On slide 65 it says "Architect can do: Multiple instances of the same plugin." How do I achieve this?

Comment: My initial answer was completely wrong, seeing example in the slides helped to update it

Comment: Wow your awesome, I haven't tried it but that looks like the right idea. Thanks for your help.